# incrementing inside a function python

Tags: python

I'm doing a beginner python course and created a very simple function that tells you how much your holiday costs given the return flight cost, hotel cost (per day) and car rental (weekly).
This was fine however the next step is to find out how long you can stay in a country given a budget of 1000.
My logic is to start the duration at 1 and try and get the function to run and check if the `cost_of_trip` is less than 1000. if it is it will increment duration and run again. Once the `cost_of_trip` exceeds 1000 it will stop and return the previous duration value. Tried several while loops but can't get it to increment more than once.

this is the basic function

```
import math
def duration_function (return_flight,hotel_cost,car_rental,):
    duration = 1
    car_rental = math.ceil((duration/7)) * car_rental
    cost_of_trip = return_flight + (hotel_cost * duration) + car_rental
    while cost_of_trip <=1000:
        duration += 1 
    return duration
```

tried several versions of this while loop

an example input would be

```
london_duration = duration_function(
    hotel_cost = 30,
    car_rental = 120,
    return_flight = 250,
)
print ("London: " + str(london_duration))
```

With the function listed above this just runs as an infinite loop.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. Currently this code does nothing besides defining a function. There is also nothing being incremented here.

Comment: it could be your budget got burst in 1st loop:) post your full code and increase 1000 to 100000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `duration_function` has no `return` statement, so it will never work. I would suggest the following:

```
def duration_function(budget, return_flight, hotel_cost, car_rental): # also pass the available budget
    budget = budget - return_flight
    days = 0

    while budget > 0:
        if days % 7 == 0: # add weekly car rental
            budget -= car_rental
        budget -= hotel_cost  # add daily hotel fee
        if budget > 0:
            # only add the day count if any money left
            days += 1
    return days
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the best solution and returned the values I was expecting. Was also cool to see a different method by starting with the budget and incrementing down

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
def duration_function (return_flight,hotel_cost,car_rental):
    duration = 1
    cost_of_trip= 0
    while(cost_of_trip < 1000 ):
        car_rental = math.ceil((duration/7)) * car_rental
        cost_of_trip = return_flight + (hotel_cost * duration) + car_rental
        duration+=1
    return duration
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ? I am not sure, if is it what you want and i did it in this terrible console, but try it. (in first time, when you invoke this method set "cost_of_trip" to 0)

```
import math
def duration_function (return_flight,hotel_cost,car_rental,duration, cost_of_trip):
    previous = cost_of_trip
    car_rental = math.ceil((duration/7)) * car_rental
    cost_of_trip = return_flight + (hotel_cost * duration) + car_rental
    if cost_of_trip < 1000:
       duration++
       duration_function(return_flight,hotel_cost,car_rental,duration, cost_of_trip)
    else:
       if (revious == 0):
          print("you have not enought money for this trip")
       else:
          return previous
```